# Nvidia driver install progress bar hang on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

To install the latest nvidia driver on UBUNTU 16.04 LTS, I followed the link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

Then,

sudo apt update

However, when I try to install the latest nvidia driver from the software update, additional driver tab, the progress bar hang at 95% so I never get to finish the installation.